# How to fit a wide table landscape orientation

Tags: adjustbox

I have this simple code: I can build the table on landscape orientation, but when I insert the command adjustbox, there are some erros:
Not in outer par mode
undefined conttrol sequence
...

Error package graphics division by 0.

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textheight,totalheight=\textwidth,keepaspectratio}
\begin{table}
\centering\small
\caption{Summary of analytical expression for $\textrm{PFD}_\textrm{avg}$ Calculations} \label{Summary}
        \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
  \toprule
        \textrm{Analytical Expression}   & FPT & FPT with \emph{p}PPT & FPT with \emph{np}PPT & Comments \\
  \cmidrule{1-5}
IEC-61508-6 & $ \binom{n}{n-k+1} \lambda_D^{n-k+1} \tau^{n-k} \cdot \frac{\lambda_{DU}}{\lambda_{D}}$ & $\binom{n}{n-k+1} \lambda_D^{n-k+1} \tau^{n-k} \cdot \frac{(TCF)\lambda_{DU}}{\lambda_D}\left(\frac{\tau}{n-k+2}+MRT\right)$ & &      \\
 &$\left(\frac{\tau}{n-k+2} +MRT\right)+\frac{\lambda_{DD}}{\lambda_{D}}(MTTR) $ & $ +\frac{(1-TCF)\lambda_{DU}}{\lambda_D}\left(\frac{\tau_{OH}}{n-k+2}+MRT\right)+\frac{\lambda_{DD}}{\lambda_D}MTTR  $ & & \\
Simplified  & $\binom{n}{n-k+1}\frac{(\lambda_{DU}\tau)^{n-k+1}}{n-k+2}$ &  &  &  \\
Formulas & & & & \\
Non-Approximate& $1-\sum_{x=k}^n \left[S(k,n,x) \cdot \frac{1-e^{-x \cdot \lambda \cdot \tau}}{x \cdot \lambda \cdot \tau} \right]$& $1-$ & $1-$ & $S(k,n,x) = \sum_{y=k}^n \left[\binom{n}{x} \cdot \binom{x}{y} \cdot (-1)^{x-y}\right] $ \\
Equations & & $\sum_{x=k}^n \left[S(k,n,x).\frac{1-e^{-x\lambda t_{TD}}}{x\lambda t_{TD}}.\frac{1}{m}.\sum_{i=1}^m\left(e^{-x(1-E)\lambda(i-1)t_{TD}}\right)\right]$&$\sum_{x=k}^n \left[S(k,n,x) \cdot \sum_{i=1}^m \left( e^{x \cdot (1-TCF) \cdot \lambda \cdot t_{i-1}} \cdot \frac{1-e^{-x \cdot \lambda \cdot t_{TDi}}}{x \cdot \lambda \cdot \tau} \right) \right]$ &$ \hspace{5 mm}\textrm{for}  \hspace{3 mm}  x=k,...,n$ \\
$\Delta$-Testing & $ \frac{n!(\lambda_{DU} \tau)^{n-k+1}}{(n-k+2)!(k-1)!}$ & $\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=0}^{n-k} \binom{n}{j} ((i-1)\lambda_b t_{TD} )^j \frac{(n-j)!(\lambda t_{TD})^{n-j-k+1}}{(n-j-k+2)!(k-1)!} $ &  &  \\
 & &  $+  \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=n-k+1}^{n} \binom{n}{j} ((i-1)\lambda_b t_{TD})^j$& & \\ 
  Policy & & & & \\                         
   \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Please augment your code snippets so that it becomes a minimal (working or non-working) example -- starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` -- that generates the problem you're trying to fix. Please also indicate which TeX distribution -- e.g., MikTeX 2.9, TeXLive2013, etc -- you're using.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you need the `adjustbox` package and its eponymous environment to typeset your table. I would, instead, use the `\resizebox{}{}{...}` command of the `graphicx` package. If you set `!` as the second argument of the `\resizebox` command, the object's aspect ratio will be preserved automatically.

Separately, I would recommend that you employ the `sidewaystable` environment of the `rotating` package instead of using separate, nested `landscape` and `table` environments. And, since the width of the table is going to be reduced to that of the (rotated) text block, there's no need to provide either a `\centering` or a `\small` instruction. I would, though, use an instruction such as `\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}` to increase the separation between the rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,amsmath,booktabs,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Summary of analytical expression for $\textrm{PFD}_\textrm{avg}$ Calculations} 
   \label{Summary}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2} % increase spacing between rows
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule
\textrm{Analytical Expression}   & FPT & FPT with \emph{p}PPT & FPT with \emph{np}PPT & Comments \\
\midrule{1-5}
% < Body of tabular environment >                     
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}} % end of scope of \resizebox
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: As you've noted in a comment, fitting your table into the available space doesn't look "nice", as the resulting font size is rather small. The main culprit is the formulas in the various cells are very wide. I've taken a stab at improving the look of the table by choosing different line breaks. I've also made a few more changes which, taken together, also contribute to a nicer-looking table. E.g., I've chosen an upright roman font for the variable names, and I allow line breaks in the first column. To keep the math expressions that are now broken across lines nice and compact, I've placed them in separate `array` environment. You can change all this, of course, to suit your needs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,rotating,amsmath,booktabs,graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
% Define appearance of variable names, say, \textnormal
\newcommand{\V}[1]{\textnormal{#1}} 
  \newcommand\TCF{\V{TCF}}
  \newcommand\MRT{\V{MRT}}
  \newcommand\MTTR{\V{MTTR}}
  \newcommand\DD{\V{DD}}
  \newcommand\DU{\V{DU}}
  \newcommand\OH{\V{OH}}
  \newcommand\TD{\V{TD}}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Summary of analytical expression for $\textrm{PFD}_\textrm{avg}$ Calculations} 
\label{Summary}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{$ %start math mode as we're using "array" environment
\begin{array}{@{} >{\raggedright}p{2.8cm} llll @{}}
\toprule
\textnormal{Analytical Expression} & 
\textnormal{FPT} & \textnormal{FPT with \emph{p}PPT} & 
\textnormal{FPT with \emph{np}PPT} & \textnormal{Comments} \\
\midrule{1-5} 
\textnormal{IEC-61508-6} & 
\binom{n}{n-k+1} \lambda_D^{n-k+1} \tau^{n-k}  \frac{\lambda_{\DU}}{\lambda_{D}} & 
\binom{n}{n-k+1} \lambda_D^{n-k+1} \tau^{n-k}  \frac{(\TCF)\lambda_{\DU}}{\lambda_D}
\left(\frac{\tau}{n-k+2}+\MRT\right)\\
& \left(\frac{\tau}{n-k+2} +\MRT\right)
+\frac{\lambda_{\DD}}{\lambda_{D}}(\MTTR)  & 
\quad {}+\frac{(1-\TCF)\lambda_{\DU}}{\lambda_D}
\left(\frac{\tau_{\OH}}{n-k+2}+\MRT\right)
+\frac{\lambda_{\DD}}{\lambda_D}\MTTR \\ \addlinespace
\textnormal{Simplified Formulas}  & 
\binom{n}{n-k+1}\frac{(\lambda_{\DU}\tau)^{n-k+1}}{n-k+2} \\ \addlinespace
\textnormal{Non-Approximate Equations} & 
1-\sum_{x=k}^n \left[S(k,n,x)  \frac{1-e^{-x \lambda \tau}}{x \lambda \tau} \right]& 
\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
1-\sum_{x=k}^n \Bigl[S(k,n,x)\frac{1-e^{-x\lambda t_{\TD}}}{x\lambda t_{\TD}}\\
\quad\times \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m\left(e^{-x(1-E)\lambda(i-1)t_{\TD}}\right)\Bigr] 
\end{array} & 
\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  1-\sum_{x=k}^n \Bigl[S(k,n,x)\\
  \quad\times\sum_{i=1}^m \left( e^{(x  (1-\TCF)  \lambda  t_{i-1})} \,
  \frac{1-e^{-x  \lambda  t_{\TD i}}}{x  \lambda  \tau} \right) \Bigr]
\end{array} & 
\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  S(k,n,x) = \sum_{y=k}^n \left[\binom{n}{x}  \binom{x}{y}  (-1)^{x-y}\right] \\
  \quad\text{for $x=k,\dots,n$}
\end{array}  \\ 
\addlinespace
\textnormal{$\Delta$-Testing Policy} & 
\frac{n!(\lambda_{\DU} \tau)^{n-k+1}}{(n-k+2)!(k-1)!} &
\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}} 
  \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=0}^{n-k} \binom{n}{j} \Bigl[\bigl((i-1)\lambda_b t_{\TD} \bigr)^j \\
  \qquad \times \frac{(n-j)!(\lambda t_{\TD})^{n-j-k+1}}{(n-j-k+2)!(k-1)!}\Bigr] \\
  \quad{}+\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=n-k+1}^{n} \binom{n}{j} \bigl((i-1)\lambda_b t_{\TD}\bigr)^j
\end{array} \\                         
\bottomrule
\end{array} $} % end of scope of \resizebox
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Mico, my next questions will be more clear. I am using Tex maker 4.0.1. But still the table does not look nice, it is fit to one page, but the size of the text is too small.

Comment: @Wilmer - The font size that results from the `\resizebox` operation is quite small by necessity, as the formulas you have in the table are rather wide. Any chance you could find better line breaks and/or simplify the expressions?

Comment: @Wilmer - You're welcome! Please feel free to upvote and/or accept my answer. ;-)

Comment: Upvoted. This is an excellent answer : )

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a float into a box this way, i.e. you need to place the `table` environment *outside* of `adjustbox`, not inside! You could also just add `float=table` to the adjustbox keys as shown below.

Note that scaling text like here in the table is not a good idea as the font is not designed to scale a lot. See [Why not scale elements that contain text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425453/36296) for more details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}


\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textheight-2\baselineskip,totalheight=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,rotate=90,center,
    caption={Summary of analytical expression for $\textrm{PFD}_\textrm{avg}$ Calculations}, label={Summary},
    float=table}
\small
        \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
  \toprule
        \textrm{Analytical Expression}   & FPT & FPT with \emph{p}PPT & FPT with \emph{np}PPT & Comments \\
  \cmidrule{1-5}
IEC-61508-6 & $ \binom{n}{n-k+1} \lambda_D^{n-k+1} \tau^{n-k} \cdot \frac{\lambda_{DU}}{\lambda_{D}}$ & $\binom{n}{n-k+1} \lambda_D^{n-k+1} \tau^{n-k} \cdot \frac{(TCF)\lambda_{DU}}{\lambda_D}\left(\frac{\tau}{n-k+2}+MRT\right)$ & &      \\
 &$\left(\frac{\tau}{n-k+2} +MRT\right)+\frac{\lambda_{DD}}{\lambda_{D}}(MTTR) $ & $ +\frac{(1-TCF)\lambda_{DU}}{\lambda_D}\left(\frac{\tau_{OH}}{n-k+2}+MRT\right)+\frac{\lambda_{DD}}{\lambda_D}MTTR  $ & & \\
Simplified  & $\binom{n}{n-k+1}\frac{(\lambda_{DU}\tau)^{n-k+1}}{n-k+2}$ &  &  &  \\
Formulas & & & & \\
Non-Approximate& $1-\sum_{x=k}^n \left[S(k,n,x) \cdot \frac{1-e^{-x \cdot \lambda \cdot \tau}}{x \cdot \lambda \cdot \tau} \right]$& $1-$ & $1-$ & $S(k,n,x) = \sum_{y=k}^n \left[\binom{n}{x} \cdot \binom{x}{y} \cdot (-1)^{x-y}\right] $ \\
Equations & & $\sum_{x=k}^n \left[S(k,n,x).\frac{1-e^{-x\lambda t_{TD}}}{x\lambda t_{TD}}.\frac{1}{m}.\sum_{i=1}^m\left(e^{-x(1-E)\lambda(i-1)t_{TD}}\right)\right]$&$\sum_{x=k}^n \left[S(k,n,x) \cdot \sum_{i=1}^m \left( e^{x \cdot (1-TCF) \cdot \lambda \cdot t_{i-1}} \cdot \frac{1-e^{-x \cdot \lambda \cdot t_{TDi}}}{x \cdot \lambda \cdot \tau} \right) \right]$ &$ \hspace{5 mm}\textrm{for}  \hspace{3 mm}  x=k,...,n$ \\
$\Delta$-Testing & $ \frac{n!(\lambda_{DU} \tau)^{n-k+1}}{(n-k+2)!(k-1)!}$ & $\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=0}^{n-k} \binom{n}{j} ((i-1)\lambda_b t_{TD} )^j \frac{(n-j)!(\lambda t_{TD})^{n-j-k+1}}{(n-j-k+2)!(k-1)!} $ &  &  \\
 & &  $+  \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=n-k+1}^{n} \binom{n}{j} ((i-1)\lambda_b t_{TD})^j$& & \\ 
  Policy & & & & \\                         
   \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```