# How can i put evenly 3 tabulars in one beamer slide?

Tags: tables, beamer

I want to create a slide on **beamer** with 3 tables. I want the two of them side by side (like in the picture below) and the third one under them.

I successfully put the 2 tables side by side using `\quad`.

My code so far is:

```
\begin{frame}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\definecolor{wildblueyonder}{rgb}{0.64, 0.68, 0.82}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{AAACED}} p{1.5cm}}

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{ |l|S|S|c| }
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Classical multiple lm} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{wildblueyonder}
 & Estimate & Std. Error & p-value \\
\hline
intercept & 21.8100 & 0.5723 & $<2e-16$ \\
r.limit & 0.4872 & 0.3775 & 0.1997 \\
conc & -0.9541 & 0.0352 & $<2e-16$ \\
log.t & -2.7720 & 0.0377 & $<2e-16$ \\
log.rho & -1.4140 & 0.0186 & $<2e-16$ \\
V.esc & 0.0001 & 0.0001 & 0.2544 \\
V.t & 0.0021 & 0.0044 & 0.6368 \\
Metal & 0.0427 & 0.0145 & 0.0040 \\
\textbf{F test} & \cellcolor{lightgray} & \cellcolor{lightgray} & \textcolor{red}{$<2e-16$} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\quad %space between tables

\begin{tabular}{ |l|S|S|c| }
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Canonical multiple lm} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{wildblueyonder}
 & Estimate & Std. Error & p-value \\
\hline
intercept & -7.4181 & 0.0067 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.1 & -0.2536 & 0.0038 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.2 & 0.6747 & 0.0053 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.3 & -0.4879 & 0.0645 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.4 & -0.0336 & 0.0081 & 0.0001 \\
Comp.5 & 0.1427 & 0.0097 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.6 & -2.2291 & 0.0284 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.7 & 1.5929 & 0.0409 & $<2e-16$ \\
\textbf{F test} & \cellcolor{lightgray} & \cellcolor{lightgray} & \textcolor{red}{$<2e-16$} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{frame}
```

Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: Show some code! Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you got so far.

Comment: here you are!!!

Comment: what is `\tl`? please provide complete bur small document with your frame beginning with `\documentclass{beamer}` followed with preamble with yours definition of new commands  and frame with tables and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Sorry guys i forgot about it! 
i use greek beamer so when i want to write an english word i have to put it in \tl{word}

Comment: Three tables on one side? Whooow! Please don't, that's too much, even one table is too much unless you highlight a column, a row, or a cell one at a time during presentation.

Comment: Can you please make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Please have a look at https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/ http://betterposters.blogspot.de/2012/08/the-data-prison.html and https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't recommend to put so much information on a single slide. The fontsize needs to be so small, nobody will to be able to read it anyway

Don't scale text, either reduce the amount of text on the slide or use a smaller font size. For more information, please have a look at [Why not scale elements that contain text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text)

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\definecolor{wildblueyonder}{rgb}{0.64, 0.68, 0.82}
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{AAACED}}l}

\usepackage{lmodern}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\fontsize{5.5pt}{8pt}\selectfont
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |l|S|S|c| }
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Classical multiple lm} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{wildblueyonder}
 & Estimate & Std. Error & p-value \\
\hline
intercept & 21.8100 & 0.5723 & $<2e-16$ \\
r.limit & 0.4872 & 0.3775 & 0.1997 \\
conc & -0.9541 & 0.0352 & $<2e-16$ \\
log.t & -2.7720 & 0.0377 & $<2e-16$ \\
log.rho & -1.4140 & 0.0186 & $<2e-16$ \\
V.esc & 0.0001 & 0.0001 & 0.2544 \\
V.t & 0.0021 & 0.0044 & 0.6368 \\
Metal & 0.0427 & 0.0145 & 0.0040 \\
\textbf{F test} & \cellcolor{lightgray} & \cellcolor{lightgray} & \textcolor{red}{$<2e-16$} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{ |l|S|S|c| }
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Canonical multiple lm} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{wildblueyonder}
 & Estimate & Std. Error & p-value \\
\hline
intercept & -7.4181 & 0.0067 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.1 & -0.2536 & 0.0038 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.2 & 0.6747 & 0.0053 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.3 & -0.4879 & 0.0645 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.4 & -0.0336 & 0.0081 & 0.0001 \\
Comp.5 & 0.1427 & 0.0097 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.6 & -2.2291 & 0.0284 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.7 & 1.5929 & 0.0409 & $<2e-16$ \\
\textbf{F test} & \cellcolor{lightgray} & \cellcolor{lightgray} & \textcolor{red}{$<2e-16$} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\smallskip\smallskip

\begin{tabular}{ |l|S|S|c| }
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Canonical multiple lm} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{wildblueyonder}
 & Estimate & Std. Error & p-value \\
\hline
intercept & -7.4181 & 0.0067 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.1 & -0.2536 & 0.0038 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.2 & 0.6747 & 0.0053 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.3 & -0.4879 & 0.0645 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.4 & -0.0336 & 0.0081 & 0.0001 \\
Comp.5 & 0.1427 & 0.0097 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.6 & -2.2291 & 0.0284 & $<2e-16$ \\
Comp.7 & 1.5929 & 0.0409 & $<2e-16$ \\
\textbf{F test} & \cellcolor{lightgray} & \cellcolor{lightgray} & \textcolor{red}{$<2e-16$} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To free the data from data prison

[image]

I suggest to use the `booktabs` package

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tiny
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lS[table-format=-2.4]S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=1e-2,table-comparator = true,table-number-alignment = center]@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Classical multiple lm} \\
\midrule
 & {Estimate} & {Std. Error} & {p-value} \\
 \cmidrule(rl){2-2} \cmidrule(rl){3-3} \cmidrule(rl){4-4}
intercept & 21.8100 & 0.5723 & <2e-16 \\
r.limit & 0.4872 & 0.3775 & 0.1997 \\
conc & -0.9541 & 0.0352 & <2e-16 \\
log.t & -2.7720 & 0.0377 & <2e-16 \\
log.rho & -1.4140 & 0.0186 & <2e-16 \\
V.esc & 0.0001 & 0.0001 & 0.2544 \\
V.t & 0.0021 & 0.0044 & 0.6368 \\
Metal & 0.0427 & 0.0145 & 0.0040 \\
\midrule
F test & & & <2e-16 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{@{}lS[table-format=-2.4]S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=1e-2,table-comparator = true,table-number-alignment = center]@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Classical multiple lm} \\
\midrule
 & {Estimate} & {Std. Error} & {p-value} \\
 \cmidrule(rl){2-2} \cmidrule(rl){3-3} \cmidrule(rl){4-4}
intercept & 21.8100 & 0.5723 & <2e-16 \\
r.limit & 0.4872 & 0.3775 & 0.1997 \\
conc & -0.9541 & 0.0352 & <2e-16 \\
log.t & -2.7720 & 0.0377 & <2e-16 \\
log.rho & -1.4140 & 0.0186 & <2e-16 \\
V.esc & 0.0001 & 0.0001 & 0.2544 \\
V.t & 0.0021 & 0.0044 & 0.6368 \\
Metal & 0.0427 & 0.0145 & 0.0040 \\
\midrule
F test & & & <2e-16 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\smallskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}lS[table-format=-2.4]S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=1e-2,table-comparator = true,table-number-alignment = center]@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Classical multiple lm} \\
\midrule
 & {Estimate} & {Std. Error} & {p-value} \\
 \cmidrule(rl){2-2} \cmidrule(rl){3-3} \cmidrule(rl){4-4}
intercept & 21.8100 & 0.5723 & <2e-16 \\
r.limit & 0.4872 & 0.3775 & 0.1997 \\
conc & -0.9541 & 0.0352 & <2e-16 \\
log.t & -2.7720 & 0.0377 & <2e-16 \\
log.rho & -1.4140 & 0.0186 & <2e-16 \\
V.esc & 0.0001 & 0.0001 & 0.2544 \\
V.t & 0.0021 & 0.0044 & 0.6368 \\
Metal & 0.0427 & 0.0145 & 0.0040 \\
\midrule
F test & & & <2e-16 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are an angel <3