# Fit table in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

I am using the `rescale` option that was suggested in the other posts in this forum to fit a table in `beamer`. However, the contents of the table move out of the frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
%%\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\scalebox{0.7}{
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{ }
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
Name & Name&Name&NameName&NameName\\ 
\hline
NameName&-&-&-&-\\
NameName&NameName B &NameName B &- &NameName B\\
NameName&NameName A&NameName A&NameName A&NameName A\\
NameName&NameName B &NameName &-&- \\
NameName&NameName C&NameName C&NameName C&-\\
NameName&-&NameName&-&-\\
NameName&-&NameName&-&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
\end{document}
```

Could someone help me to identify what's wrong in syntax that I am using?

[image]

Comment: Snapshot of the output is attached.

Comment: please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Don't forget to employ `frame` environments in a `beamer` document.
- In a `beamer` document, `table` and `figure` environments do not "float", in the LaTeX-specific sense. Hence, the main reason for using `table` and `figure` environments -- to act as "wrappers" around the core material -- is gone. The general recommendation: don't use `table` and `figure` environments in `beamer` documents.
- For your document, get rid of the `begin{table}` and `\end{table}` directives and place the argument of `\caption` in the frame title.
- There's not much to say about the specific `tabular` environment at hand. (Obviously, the many instances of NameName will get replaced with something more relevant...) The usual tricks and tips for making tabular material fit inside the text block therefore do not appear to provide much traction. I suggest that you use, *for the specific table at hand*, a `\resizebox` directive to make it fit inside the width of the text block.
- No need to load the `graphicx` package explicitly: In the `beamer` document class, this package is loaded automatically.

Here, then, is how I would rewrite your code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Tissue-specific expression of isoenzymes of 
  NameNamelase for seven different species}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  Name & Name&Name&NameName&NameName\\
  \hline
  NameName&-&-&-&-\\
  NameName&NameName B &NameName B &- &NameName B\\
  NameName&NameName A&NameName A&NameName A&NameName A\\
  NameName&NameName B &NameName &-&- \\
  NameName&NameName C&NameName C&NameName C&-\\
  NameName&-&NameName&-&-\\
  NameName&-&NameName&-&\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
} % end of scope of "\resizebox"  directive
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like to know whether it is possible to highlight the first column and first row in a different color

Comment: @Natasha - The short answer to your follow-up queston is, "yes". However, not knowing which color, or colors, you have in mind, I can't give a specific longer answer. All I can suggest for now is that you familiarize yourself with the [colortbl](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl) package and its `\rowcolor` and `\columncolor` macros.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with table and the resizebox.

Comment: @DavidBeauchemin - You're welcome. :-) Incidentally, while I did suggest using the `\resizebox` method for the table at hand, this method should not be regarded as a panacea or first-best solution. I recommended it for the table at hand purely because no other solution approach seemed feasible. In my experience, the `\resizebox` should not be employed once if the implied shrinkage exceeds about 20%.

Comment: @Mico I understasnd. Still a good workaround in last resort.

Answer (score 1):

I frequently do this by setting the font size of the contents of the table to tiny.

[image]

When You preview in PDF it looks as follows:
[image]