# A Problem with multicolumn

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn

I've got a problem with multicolumn. I have a big table and when I use the command as below I get the following error:

```
Misplaced \omit. \multispan ->\omit   \@multispan l.468 \end{tabular}}
```

I have reported below the only line in which if I delete the `\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{ADCS}}` and replace it with only  `\textbf{ADCS}` everything works.

I have other lines that have the same format of this one and they don't give me any mistake ( like the one below `\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Payload}} &  &  & \textbf{5} & \textbf{20} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{6} \\` )

Do you have any idea why it does so?

```
\begin{table}[h!] 
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% 
\centering \begin{tabular}{r c c c c c r} 
     \midrule 
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{ADCS}} & & & \textbf{2.278} & \textbf{5} & 
    \textbf{0.114} & \textbf{2.392} \\ 
\midrule 
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Payload}} &  &  & \textbf{5} & \textbf{20} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{6} \\   
    \midrule     
\end{tabular}}
 \caption{\label{tab:list_equipment} List of equipment} 
\end{table}
```

Preamble:

```
% ==================== DOCUMENT CLASS ==================== %
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
% ==================== PACKAGES ==================== %
\usepackage[portrait]{geometry}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[page,header]{appendix}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{numprint}

\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{url, lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Please don't use `\resizebox` for elements that contain text, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425453/36296

Comment: *This* code compiles fine.

Answer (score 1):

it is not clear if the answer of [user165329](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/165329/user165329) is real answer or is actually part of question. anyway, this table can be formatted (to my taste, of course) on better way:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcommand{\mcl}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{#1}}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}


%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \small
    \sisetup{detect-weight}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                            r
                            S[table-format=2.0]
                       *{2}{S[table-format=1.4]}
                            S[table-format=1.3]
                            S[table-format=1.5]
                            S[table-format=1.3]
                            }
    \toprule
\thead{FUNCTIONAL\\ SUBSYSTEM}
& {\thead{\#}}
& {\thead{Mass {[kg]}\\ per unit}}
& {\thead{Total\\ Mass {[kg]}}}
& {\thead{Margin\\ {[\%]}}}
& {\thead{Margin\\ {[kg]}}}
& {\thead{Mass {[kg]}\\ with Margin}}                                               \\
    \midrule
\mcl{Payload}       &       &           & \B        & \B 2  & \B 1      & \B 6      \\
    \midrule
    Detector        & 5     & 1         & 5         & 20    & 1         & 6         \\
    \midrule
\textbf{ADCS}       &       &           & \B 2.278  & \B 5  & \B 0.114  & \B 2.392  \\
    \midrule
Reaction Wheel      & 4     & 0.24      & 0.96      & 5     & 0.048     & 1.008     \\
Fine Sun Sensor     & 2     & 0.0037    & 0.0074    & 5     & 0.0004    & 0.008     \\
Coarse Sun Sensor   & 10    & 0.01      & 0.1       & 5     & 0.005     & 0.105     \\
Magnetometer        & 2     & 0.1       & 0.2       & 5     & 0.01      & 0.210     \\
Magnetic Torquer    & 3     & 0.3       & 0.9       & 5     & 0.045     & 0.945     \\
GPS                 & 2     & 0.0003    & 0.0006    & 5     & 0.00003   & 0.001     \\
IMU                 & 2     & 0.055     & 0.11      & 5     & 0.0055    & 0.116     \\
    \midrule \mcl{Communication} &       &           & \B 0.856  & \B 5  & \B 0.043  & \B 0.899  \\
    \midrule
Patch Antenna       & 2     & 0.08      & 0.16      & 5     & 0.008     & 0.168     \\
Eyestar Antenna     & 2     & 0.143     & 0.286     & 5     & 0.0143    & 0.300     \\
Transciever         & 1     & 0.42      & 0.42      & 5     & 0.021     & 0.441     \\
    \midrule
\mcl{Propulsion}    &       &           & \B 2.480  & \B 6.613  & \B 0.164  & \B 2.644  \\
    \midrule
20N Thruster        & 1     & 0.65      & 0.65      & 5     & 0.0325    & 0.683         \\
Tank                & 1     & 1.3       & 1.3       & 5     & 0.065     & 1.365         \\
Feeding Lines       & /     & 0.2       & 0.2       & 25    & 0.05      & 0.250         \\
Pyrotechnical Valve & 1     & 0.15      & 0.15      & 5     & 0.00075   & 0.158         \\
 Fill \& Drain Valve    & 2 & 0.09      & 0.18      & 5     & 0.009     & 0.189         \\
    \midrule
\mcl{OBDH}          &       &           &           &       &           &               \\
    \midrule
\mcl{Structure}     &       &           &           &       &           &               \\
    \midrule
\mcl{Thermal Control}   &   &           &           &       &           &               \\
\mcl{EPS}           &       &           &           &       &           &               \\
\mcl{Harness}       &       &           &           &       &           &               \\
    \midrule
Propellant          &       &           &           &       &           &               \\
Pressurizer         &       &           &           &       &           &               \\
    \midrule
\mcl{Grand Total}   &       &           &           &  \textbf{kg} &    &               \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{ List of equipment}
\label{tab:list_equipment}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hum. Nothing Minimal in your preamble. Not really a Working example either. A `MWE` could look like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r c c c c c r}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{ADCS}} & & & \textbf{2.278} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{0.114} & \textbf{2.392} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Payload}} &  &  & \textbf{5} & \textbf{20} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{6} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which compiles fine.