# I'd like to put a table and an image at the same height (subfloat)

Tags: subfloats

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{plot/figlior.png}}
    \renewcommand\intextsep{5}
\subfloat{\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}
            \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|c}
                &Low&OR&Upper\\
                \toprule
                0&0.47&0.51&0.55\\
                1&0.59&0.7&0.82\\
                2&0.52&0.61&0.72\\
                3&0.64&0.87&1.17\\
                4&1.01&2.11&4.45\\
                $5^{+}$&0.17&1.32&7.95\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}

}
\caption{OR e Intervallo di Confidenza al 95\%}
\label{orchildren}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

You may do the following

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\resizebox {0.45 \columnwidth}{!}{
\subfigure[Line]{\centering
\includegraphics{bh.jpg}
}
}
\hfil
\resizebox {0.45 \columnwidth}{!}{
\subfigure{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0 , 0) node {\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|c}
~ & Low & OR & Upper \\
\hline
0 & 0.47 & 0.51 & 0.55 \\
1 & 0.59 & 0.7 & 0.82 \\
2 & 0.52 & 0.61 & 0.72 \\
3 & 0.64 & 0.87 & 1.17 \\
4 & 1.01 & 2.11 & 4.45 \\
$5^{+}$ & 0.17 & 1.32 & 7.95 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
\caption{OR e Intervallo di Confidenza al 95\%}
\label{orchildren}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like

> [image: subfigure]

Comment: +1, but please don't use `\resizebox` for elements that contain text, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text

Comment: @zyy when you are editing maybe you can take the opportunity to make your MWEs compilable? In this case add the documentclass and `\end{document}`. When the code is complete there is no risk that you accedentally forget to include something that influences the result, such as a package, a macro definition, etc. For this particular answer that does not seem to be the case, but in general it is good practise.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need individual captions for the image/table you could simply put them in `minipages` next to each other:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
        \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}
        \begin{tabular}{lllc}
                \toprule
            &Low&OR&Upper\\
            \midrule
            0&0.47&0.51&0.55\\
            1&0.59&0.7&0.82\\
            2&0.52&0.61&0.72\\
            3&0.64&0.87&1.17\\
            4&1.01&2.11&4.45\\
            $5^{+}$&0.17&1.32&7.95\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{OR e Intervallo di Confidenza al 95\%}
    \label{orchildren}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

*(please note that it is not recommended to use vertical lines with the `booktabs` package)*

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{plot/figlior.png}}
    \renewcommand\intextsep{5}
    \subfloat{\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}
        \raisebox{\dimexpr\height-1ex}{%
          \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|c}
            &Low&OR&Upper\\\toprule
            0&0.47&0.51&0.55\\
            1&0.59&0.7&0.82\\
            2&0.52&0.61&0.72\\
            3&0.64&0.87&1.17\\
            4&1.01&2.11&4.45\\
            $5^{+}$&0.17&1.32&7.95\\\bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
       }%   
    }
    \caption{OR e Intervallo di Confidenza al 95\%}
    \label{orchildren}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]