# threeparttable and resizebox trouble

Tags: tables, threeparttable

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}[b]
\caption{Title}
\label{tab1}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
    \hline
        Group & XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX & XXXXXXXX \tnote{1} & XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX (XXX) \\
    \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{1} & XX XXXXXXXXX & \\ & (0 years) & 9 years  & -XXXXXX (XX: -0.XXX, -0.XXX, 0.XXX) \\ 
    \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{2} & XX XX XXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXX & \\ & (1-6 years) & 1-6 years & -0.XXX (XX: -0.XXX, -0.XXX, 0.XXX) \\
    \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{3} & XXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX & \\ & (7-$<$9 years) & 7-$<$9 years & -0.XXX (XX: -0.XXX, -0.XXX, 0.XXX) \\
    \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{4} & XXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX & \\ & (9 years, XXXXXX's XXXXXXXXXX XXX) & 9 years & -0.XXX (XX: -0.XXX, -0.XXX, 0.XXX) \\
    \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{5} & XX XX XXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXX & \\ & (10-12 years) & 10-12 years & -0.XXX (XX: -0.XXX, -0.XXX, 0.XXX) \\  
    \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{6} & XXXXXXX XXX XXXXXX & \\ & ($>$ 12 years) & $>$12 years & -0.XXX (XX: -0.XXX, -0.XXX, 0.XXX) \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}%
    }
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1] The note
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

- **Question:** I need to resize a table (edit: I added the original size now) to fit the page. It works when I don't use threeparttable, but I need this because I require a footnote directly under the table. It also works when I don't use resizebox. Anyone any idea how to get a table that is both adjusted to page size, meanwhile has a footnote directly under the table?

Comment: use of `\resizebox` is last desperate effort to fit table in text width.  try to avoid it with some other measures! welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text

Comment: Thanks! Yes - I am very desperate actually, haha. My table is 1/4th cut off on the right side of the document, and I really need that footnote..

Comment: @Sal.Doe, your edit is not helpful. please. change the table content (with adequate dummy text). is there some limitation, that you not use wide text width? can be content in your cells broken into more lines?

Comment: The size of the 2nd and 4th column cannot be broken down. I had not seen your comment before the edit. Hope this edit is helpful, else let me know!

Comment: The only thing that "works" is pushing the table to the left, while the table should preferably be a bit smaller to fit tidy.

Comment: @Sal.Doe, what you say in comments means, that you should consider to rotate table. squeezing table as you like to do, will make your table not readable. i'm afraid that i can't further help you.

Answer (score 2):

if your real table is not wider from that in your question, than the following measures fit your table in text width (so for it not need to use `\scalebox`):

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}[b]
    \caption{Title}
    \label{tab1}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} rlrr}
    \hline
Ipsum lorum dolor & Ipsum lorum dolor & Ipsum lorum dolor\tnote{1} & Ipsum lorum dolor \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{1} & Ipsum lorum dolor & \\ & Ipsum lorum dolor & Ipsum lorum dolor & Ipsum lorum dolor\\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{2} & Ipsum lorum dolor & \\ & Ipsum lorum dolor & Ipsum lorum dolor & Ipsum lorum dolor \\
    \hline
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\item[1] The note
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

you can also reduce font size, for example to `\small` and obtain even better table looks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Ah, well.. actually it is bigger, this is not the original table size. Do you need the original size to get a better idea?

Comment: @Sal.Doe, of course. my crystal ball is on vacations ... so only can suspect that your page layout as well your table are (very) different from my example.