# Undefined control sequence. l.569 \scalebox {0.55}{

Tags: scalebox

I have entered the following code:-

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\scalebox{0.55}{
```

However, I get the following error when I compile

```
"Undefined control dequence. l.569 \scalebox {0.55}{ "
```

I realize I have not closed the command with a curly bracket. However, I have inserted a table beneath this command and inserted the closing curly bracket after `\end{tabular}`. I see I have done nothing wrong - so why the error? Can someone please help? Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @NBalakrishnan `scalebox` comes with `graphicx` package as stock. Do you have it loaded?

Comment: note that the format you show is not the format tex uses for error messages, which means we can not be sure which command is undefined, always show the full error from the log, including linebreaks. However if it is `\scalebox` that is not defined, load the `graphicx` package.

Comment: Unrelated to your error: it is probably a bad idea to scale the content of a table, maybe using a smaller font size would be better. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text