# Table with different column numbers - full width

Tags: tables, beamer, multicolumn

I'm trying to generate a table in beamer like the one in the picture below

[image: Original Table]

The problem is that In the last part of the table, there are lesser columns.

I tried to overcome this issue with a combination of multicolumn and tabular.
However, so far I only managed to get misaligned columns standing at the center of the table. 
Is there a way to get the last columns to fill the whole table width, like the ones in the picture?

Thank you very much for your support.

Best regards
[image: Code generated table]

```
    %%%%%% Preamble %%%%%%
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\tikzstyle{block}=[draw opacity=0.7,line width=1.4cm]
\newcounter{nodemarkers}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usetheme{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\captionsetup[table]{font=scriptsize}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography item}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{frame number}{fg=black}
%%%%%% Beamer %%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Results}
    \begin{table}   
        \caption{ Estimation results of $RI-RF=\alpha + \beta(RM-RF)+\epsilon_i$.}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.52}[0.62]{
            \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrrr}
                \addlinespace
                \toprule
                \midrule
                \multirow{2}{1pt}{Size quintile} & \multicolumn{10}{c}{Book-to-market  equity  (BE/ME) quintiles}\\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-11}
                & Low   & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & Low   & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5 \\
                \cmidrule(lr){1-11}
                & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\boldsymbol{$\beta$}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{ \textbf{t(\boldmath$\beta$)}} \\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-11}
                Small & 20.6  & 20.8  & 20.2  & 19.4  & 15.1  & 0.30   & 0.62  & 0.84  & 1.09  & 1.80 \\
                2     & 89.7  & 89.3  & 89.3  & 89.9  & 88.5  & 0.31  & 0.60   & 0.83  & 1.09  & 1.71 \\
                3     & 209.3 & 211.9 & 210.8 & 214.8 & 210.7 & 0.31  & 0.60   & 0.84  & 1.08  & 1.66 \\
                4     & 535.1 & 537.4 & 545.4 & 551.6 & 538.7 & 0.31  & 0.61  & 0.84  & 1.09  & 1.67 \\
                Big   & 3583.7 & 2885.8 & 2819.5 & 2700.5 & 2337.9 & 0.29  & 0.59  & 0.83  & 1.08  & 1.56 \\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-11}
                & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{$R^2$}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{s(\boldsymbol{$\epsilon$})}} \\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-11}
                Small & 0.69  & 0.49  & 0.46  & 0.48  & 0.64  & 428.0   & 276.6 & 263.8 & 291.5 & 512.7 \\
                2 & 0.92  & 0.71  & 0.65  & 0.61  & 0.55  & 121.6 & 94.0    & 86.7  & 79.8  & 71.3 \\
                3 & 1.78  & 1.36  & 1.26  & 1.14  & 0.82  & 102.7 & 78.3  & 73.0    & 64.5  & 45.9 \\
                4     & 3.95  & 3.01  & 2.71  & 2.41  & 1.50   & 90.1  & 68.9  & 60.7  & 53.1  & 33.4 \\
                Big   & 30.13 & 15.87 & 12.85 & 10.44 & 4.61  & 93.6  & 63.7  & 52.7  & 44.0    & 23.6 \\
                \cmidrule(lr){1-11}
                & \multicolumn{10}{c}{Excess returns on government and corporate bonds} \\
                & \multicolumn{10}{c}{\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr} 1-5G & 6-10G & AAA & AA & A & BAA & LG \end{tabular}} \\
                \cmidrule(lr){1-11}\\
                \boldmath $\beta$    & \multicolumn{10}{c}{\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr} 0.08 & 0.13 & 0.19 & 0.20 & 0.21 & 0.22 & 0.30 \end{tabular}} \\
                \textbf{t(\boldmath $\beta$)}     & \multicolumn{10}{c}{\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr} 0.08 & 0.13 & 0.19 & 0.20 & 0.21 & 0.22 & 0.30 \end{tabular}} \\
                \boldmath$R^2$  &   \multicolumn{10}{c}{\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr} 0.07 & 0.08 & 0.14 & 0.16 & 0.17 & 0.18 & 0.29 \end{tabular}} \\
                \textbf{s(\boldsymbol{$\epsilon$})}   &   \multicolumn{10}{c}{\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr} 1.21 & 1.95 & 2.17 & 2.05 & 2.05 & 2.12 & 2.12 \end{tabular}} \\
                \midrule
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}%      
        }
    \end{table}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Following comments I tried this:

```
   %%%%%% Preamble %%%%%%
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\tikzstyle{block}=[draw opacity=0.7,line width=1.4cm]
\newcounter{nodemarkers}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usetheme{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\captionsetup[table]{font=scriptsize}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography item}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{frame number}{fg=black}
%%%%%% Beamer %%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Results}
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \tiny
        \begin{center}
         \caption{ Estimation results of $RI-RF=\alpha + \beta(RM-RF)+\epsilon_i$.}
            \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrrr}
                \toprule
                \midrule
                \multirow{2}{1pt}{Size quintile} & \multicolumn{10}{c}{Book-to-market  equity  (BE/ME) quintiles}\\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-11}
                & Low   & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & Low   & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5 \\
                \cmidrule(lr){1-11}
                & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\boldsymbol{$\beta$}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{ \textbf{t(\boldmath$\beta$)}} \\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-11}
                Small & 20.6  & 20.8  & 20.2  & 19.4  & 15.1  & 0.30   & 0.62  & 0.84  & 1.09  & 1.80 \\
                2     & 89.7  & 89.3  & 89.3  & 89.9  & 88.5  & 0.31  & 0.60   & 0.83  & 1.09  & 1.71 \\
                3     & 209.3 & 211.9 & 210.8 & 214.8 & 210.7 & 0.31  & 0.60   & 0.84  & 1.08  & 1.66 \\
                4     & 535.1 & 537.4 & 545.4 & 551.6 & 538.7 & 0.31  & 0.61  & 0.84  & 1.09  & 1.67 \\
                Big   & 3583.7 & 2885.8 & 2819.5 & 2700.5 & 2337.9 & 0.29  & 0.59  & 0.83  & 1.08  & 1.56 \\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-11}
                & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{$R^2$}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{s(\boldsymbol{$\epsilon$})}} \\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-11}
                Small & 0.69  & 0.49  & 0.46  & 0.48  & 0.64  & 428.0   & 276.6 & 263.8 & 291.5 & 512.7 \\
                2 & 0.92  & 0.71  & 0.65  & 0.61  & 0.55  & 121.6 & 94.0    & 86.7  & 79.8  & 71.3 \\
                3 & 1.78  & 1.36  & 1.26  & 1.14  & 0.82  & 102.7 & 78.3  & 73.0    & 64.5  & 45.9 \\
                4     & 3.95  & 3.01  & 2.71  & 2.41  & 1.50   & 90.1  & 68.9  & 60.7  & 53.1  & 33.4 \\
                Big   & 30.13 & 15.87 & 12.85 & 10.44 & 4.61  & 93.6  & 63.7  & 52.7  & 44.0    & 23.6 \\
                \cmidrule(lr){1-11}
                & 
                \end{tabular}
                \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
                 \multicolumn{7}{c}{Excess returns on government and corporate bonds} \\
                        1-5G & 6-10G & AAA & AA & A & BAA & LG\\
                        0.10 & 0.13 & 0.18 & 0.23 & 0.25 & 0.28 & 0.36\\
                 \midrule
                 \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \end{table}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But this is far from the table in the picture.
The second tabular doesn't have the same width as the first one and also the two tabulars seem to be apart from each other, despite belonging to the same table.
This is the result:[image]

Comment: Why don't you do two tabulars one under the other?

Comment: I agree with @CarLaTeX, make two `tabular`s. If you place them in the same `table` environment, they will share one caption etc.

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text Instead of scaling your table, I suggest to use a smaller font size

Comment: Off-topic: You don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}` with beamer

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. I used the two tabular strategy you suggested, but I still couldn't replicate the structure of the table in the first picture. The second tabular doesn't have the same width and it seems apart from the first one. Nevertheless I believe we are getting closer. Thank you. I edited my post with the solution I tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a `tabular*` environment for the upper table; that way, you can ensure that it fits inside the text block. Conversely, I would not use a `table` environment at all; instead, stick the caption into the argument of `\frametitle`.  I would also use **bold-facing** much more sparingly; actually, I wouldn't use it at all for this table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{bm}
%%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\tikzstyle{block}=[draw opacity=0.7,line width=1.4cm]
\newcounter{nodemarkers}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx} % <-- new
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usetheme{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\captionsetup[table]{font=scriptsize}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography item}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{frame number}{fg=black}
%%%%%% Beamer %%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Estimation results of 
$RI-RF = \alpha + \beta(RM-RF) + \epsilon_i$}
\scriptsize
\begingroup
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
   l*{10}{r}}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{1pt}{Size quintile} & \multicolumn{10}{c}{Book-to-market equity (BE/ME) quintiles}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-11}
& Low   & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     
& Low   & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5 \\
\cmidrule{2-11}\addlinespace
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{$\beta$} 
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{$t(\beta)$} \\
\cmidrule{2-6} \cmidrule{7-11}
Small & 20.6  & 20.8  & 20.2  & 19.4  & 15.1  & 0.30   & 0.62  & 0.84  & 1.09  & 1.80 \\
2     & 89.7  & 89.3  & 89.3  & 89.9  & 88.5  & 0.31  & 0.60   & 0.83  & 1.09  & 1.71 \\
3     & 209.3 & 211.9 & 210.8 & 214.8 & 210.7 & 0.31  & 0.60   & 0.84  & 1.08  & 1.66 \\
4     & 535.1 & 537.4 & 545.4 & 551.6 & 538.7 & 0.31  & 0.61  & 0.84  & 1.09  & 1.67 \\
Big   & 3583.7 & 2885.8 & 2819.5 & 2700.5 & 2337.9 & 0.29  & 0.59  & 0.83  & 1.08  & 1.56 \\
\cmidrule{2-11}\addlinespace
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{$R^2$} 
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{$s(\epsilon)$} \\
\cmidrule{2-6} \cmidrule{7-11}
Small & 0.69  & 0.49  & 0.46  & 0.48  & 0.64  & 428.0   & 276.6 & 263.8 & 291.5 & 512.7 \\
2 & 0.92  & 0.71  & 0.65  & 0.61  & 0.55  & 121.6 & 94.0    & 86.7  & 79.8  & 71.3 \\
3 & 1.78  & 1.36  & 1.26  & 1.14  & 0.82  & 102.7 & 78.3  & 73.0    & 64.5  & 45.9 \\
4     & 3.95  & 3.01  & 2.71  & 2.41  & 1.50   & 90.1  & 68.9  & 60.7  & 53.1  & 33.4 \\
Big   & 30.13 & 15.87 & 12.85 & 10.44 & 4.61  & 93.6  & 63.7  & 52.7  & 44.0    & 23.6 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\endgroup

\bigskip
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{7}{c}@{}}
\multicolumn{7}{c}{Excess returns on government and corporate bonds} \\[0.5ex]
\toprule
1--5G & 6--10G & AAA & AA & A & BAA & LG\\
\midrule
0.10 & 0.13 & 0.18 & 0.23 & 0.25 & 0.28 & 0.36\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice layout!

Comment: @samcarter - Many thanks for the compliment!

Comment: I noticed that you eliminated `hyperref` - could you do the same with `\usepackage{graphicx}`?

Comment: This is a very nice layout indeed and I think I'll use it instead of trying to mimic the table in the picture.  Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: @samcarter - I must confess that I've lost track of which packages are loaded automatically by the `beamer` document class. :-(

Comment: @Mico That's easy: basically all, one just has to remember the few packages which are not loaded :)

Comment: @samcarter - Good one!