# When I use tikz, it always creates a new page. Anybody could help?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was trying to insert a tex file containing the code for a tikz graph into a main tex file. However, I got a problem. The graph always stands alone in an independent page. So any words before or after the inserting command will be a page ahead or a page afterward. The tex file was automatically generated by R package "tikzDevice"

My Latex code is very simple.

```
\title{homework}
\author{me}
\date{}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \setmainfont{Microsoft Sans Serif}
  \centering
  \include{Plot1}
  crazy
  \include{Plot1}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is what happened]

My tikz tex code for the graph is as below:

```
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `\resizebox` for elements that contain text, like the graph you show us in your image. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text for other possibilities instead of `\resizebox`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the solution. I should use `\input` instead of `\include`!