# How can I get the desired output ie. Enlarge single letter?

Tags: fontsize

[image: Nuclide Notation]

I Want the desired output with ***X enlarged compared to A & Z*** but when I use the following command

```
$^A_Z{\Large X}_N$
```

It doesn't show desired output.

What could be the possible command to enlarge just a single letter?

Comment: `A,Z,N` are indexes, so they should be smaller than the normal font `X`. So, do you want the normal font `X` bigger then the indexes or even more?

Comment: I want X to be much larger.

Comment: Much larger like for `\sum`?

Answer (score 6):

You can load `mathtools` and use this code:

```
$\prescript{A}{Z}{\text{\Large$ X $}}_N$
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm using to increase the single letter the package [`relsize`](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/relsize/relsize-doc.pdf) at the page 1:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
${}^{A}_{Z} {\mbox{\Large$X$}}_N$, \quad ${}^{A}_{Z} {\mbox{\larger[3]$X$}}_N$, \quad ${}^{A}_{Z}{\mbox{\larger[6]$X$}}_N$
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wants the letter bigger than the normal size. In your example, `X`  has normal size.

Comment: @Sigur Aesthetically, that could be a good compromise. If there are any comments they are always welcome.

Comment: Scaling elements that contain text will result in a sub-optimal choice of character shape, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text. Better start with a font size that is closer to the desired target (e.g. `\Large`) and scale from there using a smaller scaling factor. This will make the letters easier to read.

Comment: @Sebastiano, it was not mine, anyway. :-)