# literature review table in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, presentations

i am trying to create something like this - a literature summary review. I am quite new to latex and struggle quite a bit with tables. How can i create something similiar to the example?

My table has 12 columns and 6 rows

[image]

My environment

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%
% Choose how your presentation looks.
%
% For more themes, color themes and font themes, see:
% http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html
%
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{beaver} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

Comment: This won't fit on a frame and if you somehow mange to squeeze it on a frame, it will be so tiny nobody will be able to read this (my personal opinion)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with samcarter that the text will be to small. Nevertheless here is an example how you could do it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textpos}


\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.83, 0.83, 0.83}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

{
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{beaver} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}










\begin{document}

\begin{frame}



\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%


\begin{tabular}{|llllll|}
\toprule
\thead{Study, Setting and \\ Sample Size} & \thead{Study Design} & \thead{Summary of Intervention} & \thead{Health System \\ Building Blocks \\ Included} & \thead{Summary of Findings} & \thead{Risk of Bias \\ Assessment} \\

\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray}
Column 1 Row 1 & Column 2 Row 1 & Column 3 Row 1 & Column 4 Row 1 & Column 5 Row 1 & Column 6 Row 1 \\
Column 1 Row 2 & Column 2 Row 2 & Column 3 Row 2 & Column 4 Row 2 & Column 5 Row 2 & Column 6 Row 2 \\
\rowcolor{lightgray}
Column 1 Row 3 & Column 2 Row 3 & Column 3 Row 3 & Column 4 Row 3 & Column 5 Row 3 & Column 6 Row 3 \\
Column 1 Row 4 & Column 2 Row 4 & Column 3 Row 4 & Column 4 Row 4 & Column 5 Row 4 & Column 6 Row 4 \\
\bottomrule
doc:10.137 & &  & & & \\
\end{tabular}
}

\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

This results in the following table. [image]

Comment: A small comment: you don't need the `color` package with beamer and instead of  loading `colortbl` better do `\documentclass[xcolor={table}]{beamer}`

Comment: Normally I would complain that scaling elements that contain text is not a good idea (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text) but it does not matter here, because it anyway won't be readable :)