# Tikz picture, beamer, Putting text in a point in a way that the placement of other components doesn't change

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, floats

I have drawn a tikzpicture in a frame and everything was ok. But now I should add a text to it, and in every way I try to add the text, the placement of other components changes and ruins everything (I have blank space and want to place the text in there). I couldn't find any answer. How should i do that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\tikzset{module/.append style={top color=\col,bottom color=\col}}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\usepackage{verbatim}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

        \begin{frame}{Title}
        \begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={\textwidth}{\textheight},center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
              level 1 concept/.append style={text width=3cm,font=\sffamily\LARGE,level distance=6cm,sibling angle=110,
              every child/.style={concept color=orange}},
              level 2 concept/.append style={text width=3cm,font=\sffamily\LARGE,level distance=5cm,sibling angle=90,
              every child/.style={concept color=blue!80!black}}
              ]
          \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
            node[concept,scale=0.8] {\huge A}
            [clockwise from=-10]
            child[] {
              node[concept] {B}
              [clockwise from=45]
                  child[sibling angle=45] { node[concept] {D}}
                  child[sibling angle=45] { node[concept] {E } }
                  child[sibling angle=45] { node[concept] {F}}
                  child[sibling angle=45] { node[concept] {G} }
            } 
            child[] {
              node[concept] {C}
              [clockwise from=-45]
                child[]{ node[concept]{ H}}
                child[]{ node[concept]{ I}}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}  
        \end{adjustbox}
        \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is my code and its output is as follow:

[image]

I want to add text and get something like follow without relocating other components.

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I added example code and the desired output. Thanks.

Comment: @user137927 Can make your code fragment compilable by including all the required packages and libraries?

Comment: @samcarter I edited the code. I hope it ok now.

Comment: I think the [textpos package](https://ctan.org/pkg/textposcan) can solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `remember picture, overlay` options you can prevent certain parts of a `tikzpiture` to influence the total size and this the positioning on the page. In addition I would [not scale elements that contain text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text), instead a simple solution is to use the `small mindmap` style:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

   \begin{frame}{Title}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            small mindmap,
              level 1 concept/.append style={
                sibling angle=110,
                every child/.style={concept color=orange}
              },
              level 2 concept/.append style={
                sibling angle=90,
                every child/.style={concept color=blue!80!black}
              }
              ]
          \path[concept color=black,text=white]
            node[concept,scale=0.8] {A}
            [clockwise from=-10]
            child[visible on=<2->] {
              node[concept] {B}
              [clockwise from=45]
                  child[sibling angle=45,visible on=<3->] { node[concept] {D}}
                  child[sibling angle=45,visible on=<3->] { node[concept] {E } }
                  child[sibling angle=45,visible on=<3->] { node[concept] {F}}
                  child[sibling angle=45,visible on=<3->] { node[concept] {G} }
            } 
            child[visible on=<2->] {
              node[concept] {C}
              [clockwise from=-45]
                child[visible on=<4->]{ node[concept]{ H}}
                child[visible on=<4->]{ node[concept]{ I}}
            };
            \begin{scope}[remember picture, overlay]
           \node at (-3,2) {some text};  
           \end{scope}          
        \end{tikzpicture}  
        \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. about scaling, can you please guide me how to do it?

Comment: @user137927 Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

```
 \documentclass{beamer}

 \usepackage{tikz} 
 \usepackage{smartdiagram}
 \usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
 \tikzset{module/.append style={top color=\col,bottom color=\col}}
 \usepackage{adjustbox}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
 \usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
 \usepackage{verbatim}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \newcommand{\nx}{40}%number of divisions on page width
 \newcommand{\ny}{20}%number of divisions on page height
 \usepackage[absolute,overlay
 ,showboxes % comment to make vanish the box
 ]{textpos} %absolute positioning. Use 'showboxes' for viewing the textblock borders box
 \TPGrid{\nx}{\ny}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 % A grid for the absolute positioning. Very useful! It's due to Jake with some little change by me.
 \usetikzlibrary{math}
 \newcommand\myGrid{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    overlay,
    remember picture,
    shift={(current page.north west)},
    ]
    \tikzmath{
        \sdx=\nx-1;
        \sdy=\ny-1;
    }
    \draw[very thin, blue!10, xstep=\TPHorizModule, ystep=\TPVertModule]
    (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
    \draw[very thin, red!50, xstep=5*\TPHorizModule, ystep=5*\TPVertModule]
    (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,\sdx} { \node [xshift=\x*\TPHorizModule,label=below:\tiny\x,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page.north west){};}
    \foreach \y in {1,2,...,\sdy} {\node [yshift=-\y*\TPVertModule,label=right:\tiny\y,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page.north west) {};}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
 }

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \begin{document}

         \begin{frame}{Title}
 \myGrid %Comment to make vanish the grid
 \begin{textblock}{35}(5,2) %in the bracket the width of the box and in parenthesis the position of the upper left corner
         \begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={\textwidth}{\textheight},center}
         \begin{tikzpicture}[
               level 1 concept/.append style={text width=3cm,font=\sffamily\LARGE,level distance=6cm,sibling angle=110,
               every child/.style={concept color=orange}},
               level 2 concept/.append style={text width=3cm,font=\sffamily\LARGE,level distance=5cm,sibling angle=90,
               every child/.style={concept color=blue!80!black}}
               ]
           \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
             node[concept,scale=0.8] {\huge A}
             [clockwise from=-10]
             child[] {
               node[concept] {B}
               [clockwise from=45]
                   child[sibling angle=45] { node[concept] {D}}
                   child[sibling angle=45] { node[concept] {E } }
                   child[sibling angle=45] { node[concept] {F}}
                   child[sibling angle=45] { node[concept] {G} }
             } 
             child[] {
               node[concept] {C}
               [clockwise from=-45]
                 child[]{ node[concept]{ H}}
                 child[]{ node[concept]{ I}}
             };
         \end{tikzpicture}  
         \end{adjustbox}
    \end{textblock}
   \begin{textblock}{7}(5,2)
 this in my text added without relocation of the tikzpicture and any other component
   \end{textblock}
         \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

[image]