# There is a mistake in the code which I can’t solve

Tags: formatting

Please, help to resolve the following issue. I am trying to add tablenotes to a table. Once I add them above the table, I obtain the following mistake: "! Package graphics Error: Division by 0.". Below I attach all the packages that I use and the table itself:

**Packages:**

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,authordate, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex-chicago}
%\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% package for including graphics with figure-environment
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{Reference.bib}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,
              singlelinecheck = false}


\usepackage{makecell}
```

****TABLE**

```
\newpage
\centering

\begin{table}[H] 

    \bigskip
    \centering
      \begin{adjustbox}{height=0.45\textheight}
\begin{threeparttable}



 \footnotesize
 \centering

    \begin{tablenotes}
 \footnotesize
\item This table presents results of a model:

  \end{tablenotes}


\begin{tabular}{lccccc} \hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{Panel A:} Bank loans}\\ 
 &  & &  & \\\hline

 &\multicolumn{4}{c}{Bank Loans} &Bond Market \\

  \cmidrule[0.4pt](r{0.125em}){2-5}% 
  \cmidrule[0.4pt](r{0.125em}){6-6}% \\


 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
VARIABLES & a& b& c & d & e \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hline\hline
 \end{tabular}


  \end{threeparttable}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please reduce your example to a [mre]. You might even solve the problem yourself in the process!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is related to the `adjustbox` around the table, but you anyway should never scale elements which contain text ([Why not scale elements that contain text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text)), so simply remove it.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,authordate, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex-chicago}
%\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% package for including graphics with figure-environment
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{Reference.bib}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,
              singlelinecheck = false}


\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}


\newpage
\centering

\begin{table}[H] 

    \bigskip
    \centering
%     \begin{adjustbox}{height=0.45\textheight}
\begin{threeparttable}



 \footnotesize
 \centering

    \begin{tablenotes}
 \footnotesize
\item This table presents results of a model:

  \end{tablenotes}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lccccc@{}} \hline
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Panel A:} Bank loans}\\ 
 &  & &  & \\\hline

 &\multicolumn{4}{c}{Bank Loans} &Bond Market \\

  \cmidrule[0.4pt](r{0.125em}){2-5}% 
  \cmidrule[0.4pt](r{0.125em}){6-6}% \\


 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
VARIABLES & a& b& c & d & e \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hline\hline
 \end{tabular}


  \end{threeparttable}
%    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: We Ti*k*Zlings are missing your answers here a lot!