# How to force a long table to the page width

Tags: tables

I have a long table whose format I take directly from overleaf:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l||l|l|l|}
        \caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\
        
        \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}}\\ \hline 
        \endfirsthead
        
        \multicolumn{6}{c}%
        {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
        \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}}\\ \hline 
        \endhead
        
        \hline \multicolumn{6}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
        \endfoot
        
        \hline \hline
        \endlastfoot 
        One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
        One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
        One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
        One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
```

In my table I have 6 columns and since there are 6 columns the total width of the table exceeds the page. Is there a way I can fix it? Usually i use the following command for normal tables in my documents and they work perfectly well.

```
\resizebox{0.99\textwidth}{!}
```

I do not know how I can shrink the long table so that it is fit in the page like other tables.

Comment: even for normal tables it is usually best to avoid `\resizebox` as it leads to inconsistent font sizes. Just use `\small` or `\footnotesize` or whatever you need to select a suitable font before `\begin{longtable}`

Comment: please do not use external links, show the code in your question, especially links that say `Restricted, sorry you don’t have permission to load this page.`

Comment: I have changed it now. I hope its clear now

Comment: don't put `center` around longtable (it does not centre it) but as I commented first use `\small` or a different size to make the table fit, as you have not provided a complete test file can not say what font size you need as have no information about your page size or fonts.

Comment: if you could tell how the size adjusting parameter can be added in the code, I can try. Thank you

Comment: just put `\small` before `\begin{longtable}` (and `\normalsize` after `\end{longtable}` if it is not already in some group)

Comment: still it exceeds the page width

Comment: you haven't given any information on your page width so I had to guess, \footnotesize is smaller than \small, \tiny is smaller than \footnotesize

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132016/discussion-between-lalu-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: how can i check the pagewidth, sorry if it too low level question, \tiny was way too small

Comment: @Lalu Did you try `\footnotesize`?

Comment: You also can play with the value of `\tabcolsep`  (the default is 6pt, which makes 72pt for a table with 6 columns).

Answer (score 1):

You not provide MWE, so we can only ques about your pages layout. Assuming, that it is determined by `geometry` package and that dummy content of your table is close to real content, the table can be designed as follows:

[image]

It is produced by use of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachfive}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {6}{5}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {A sample long table.}, 
      label = {tab:long}
                ]{rowhead = 1,
                  colspec = {@{} X[0.5,l]X[1.2,l]X[1,l]
                                 X[0.5,l]X[1.2,l]X[1,l] @{}},
                column{3} = {rightsep=2em},
                   rowsep = 0.5pt,
                   row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
             row{eachfive} = {abovesep=1ex},
                 }                                                      
    \toprule
{First\\ column}    
    & {Second\\ column} 
        & {Third\\ column}  
            & {First\\ column}
                & {Second\\ column}
                        & {Third\\ column}                              \\
    \cmidrule[r=-0.5]{1-3}
    \cmidrule[l=-0.5]{4-6}
% table body
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\

One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\

One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\

One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\

One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\

One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\

One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\

One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\

One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\

One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\

One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As no [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) is provided, the answer is given assuming the standard `article` class.

Now, if a table width exceeds page width, then the good practice is to reduce the font size rather than resizing it. You may find the reason [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text).

Also, you may consider using fixed-width columns if reducing font size is not an option.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \footnotesize
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l||l|l|l|}
        \caption{A sample long table (reduced font size).} \label{tab:long} \\
        
        \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c||}{\textbf{Third column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{First column}}\\ \hline 
        \endfirsthead
        
        \multicolumn{6}{c}%
        {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
        \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}}\\ \hline 
        \endhead
        
        \hline \multicolumn{6}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
        \endfoot
        
        \hline \hline
        \endlastfoot 
        One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
        One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &\\
        One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &\\
        One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &\\
    \end{longtable}
    \normalsize
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \begin{longtable}{*{6}{|p{1.5cm}}|}%{|l|l|l||l|l|l|}
        \caption{A sample long table (using fixed width column).} \label{tab:long2} \\
        
        \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Third column}} & \multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{First column}}\\ \hline 
        \endfirsthead
        
        \multicolumn{6}{c}%
        {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
        \hline \multicolumn{1}{|C{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{Third column}} & \multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}|}{\textbf{First column}}\\ \hline  
        \endhead
        
        \hline \multicolumn{6}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
        \endfoot
        
        \hline \hline
        \endlastfoot 
        One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & \\
        One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &\\
        One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &\\
        One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 &\\
    \end{longtable}
    \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]