# Alignment problem with a subfigure histogram plot

Tags: graphics, subplot, pgfplots

I am facing an alignment problem with a subfigure  plots, that I do not have any clue how to fix it, and I have tried to make theme as image, but I have the same problem. The main problem is shown in the figure below. As it shows, the graphs are not aligned, or they are not of the same size (title/caption as well). The plots are made via pgfplots and subfig packges. The code used to generate them are in the end of this text. Any help is welcome!!!

Edit: The main error of the  *standalone class* as  figure

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%\usepackage{sfmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering %
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \hspace*{\fill}%
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
           
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering
  \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        title={Manufacture 1},
        set layers,axis background,
        grid=major,
        height=6cm, width=8.5cm,
        bar width=0.14cm,
        set layers,
        axis background,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
       major grid  style={dashed,draw=gray!15}, 
        ymin=1000, ymax=13000,
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.1cm}
        axis x line*=bottom,
        max space between ticks=14pt,
         xticklabel style={rotate=90,yshift=-0.05cm,xshift=0,color=black},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=true,
        ylabel={Number of Sale },
        symbolic x coords={
     BMW, VW, Honda
          },
       xtick=data,
       enlarge x limits={abs=0.01},
       enlarge x limits=0.05,
        enlarge y limits=0.05,
       nodes near coords={
       }
    ]
    \addplot [draw=none, fill=blue] coordinates {
      (BMW,  12766) 
       (VW,  12766) 
       (Honda,  12766) 
    
      };

   \addplot [draw=none,fill=red] coordinates {
     (BMW,  10901)
     (VW, 6682)    
    (Honda, 9468)
  
  
     
     };
    
  
   \addplot [draw=none, fill=green] coordinates {
     (BMW, 8679)
     (VW, 3659)    
     (Honda,  7844)
    
        
      };
    
  \legend{car 1, car 2, car 3}
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
 }
%     \caption{Subfigure A}
        \label{fig:subfig8}
    \end{subfigure}

      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
           \begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering
  \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        title={(b) Manufacture 2 },
        set layers,axis background,
        grid=major,
        height=6cm, width=8.5cm,
        max space between ticks=40pt,
        ymin=0,
        bar width=0.14cm,
        set layers,
        axis background,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
       major grid  style={dashed,draw=gray!15}, 
        ymin=1000, ymax=6000,
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.1cm}
        axis x line*=bottom,
        y tick label style={scaled ticks=base 10:-4},
           xticklabel style={rotate=90,yshift=0.1cm,xshift=0,color=black},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=true,
        symbolic x coords={BMW, VW, Honda 
          },
       xtick=data,
       enlarge x limits={abs=0.01},
       enlarge x limits=0.05,
        enlarge y limits=0.05,
       nodes near coords={
       }
    ]
    \addplot [draw=none, fill=blue] coordinates {
     (BMW, 5153)
 (VW, 4522)
 (Honda, 4522)

      };
 
  
    
  \legend{Electric Car 2060 }
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
        }
           \caption{Subfigure B}
        \label{fig:subfig9}
    \end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \hspace*{\fill}%
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
           
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering
  \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        title={Manufacture 3},
        set layers,axis background,
        grid=major,
        height=6cm, width=8.5cm,
        ymin=0,
        bar width=0.14cm,
        set layers,
        axis background,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
       major grid  style={dashed,draw=gray!15}, 
        ymin=1000, ymax=21111,
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.1cm}
        axis x line*=bottom,
           xticklabel style={rotate=90,yshift=-0.05cm,xshift=0,color=black},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=true,
        ylabel={},
        symbolic x coords={
        BMW, VW, Honda
          },
       xtick=data,
       enlarge x limits={abs=0.01},
       enlarge x limits=0.05,
        enlarge y limits=0.05,
       nodes near coords={
       }
    ]
    \addplot [draw=none, fill=red] coordinates {
(BMW, 19289)
 (VW, 20289)
 (Honda, 20289)
      };
 
   \addplot [draw=none,fill=blue] coordinates {
    (BMW,14653) 
 (VW, 20489)
      (VW, 20289)
       (Honda, 20289)
     };
    

  
   \addplot [draw=none, fill=green] coordinates {
   (BMW,14653) 
 (VW, 20489)
     
 
        
      };
    
 \legend{Car 1, Car 2, Car 3}
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
        \caption{Subfigure C}
        \label{fig:subfig8}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your code does not compile

Comment: try overleaf link https://www.overleaf.com/1387338782zkctnvntsmdc

Comment: Just because overleaf is good at hiding error messages, does not mean the code compiles https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD3J0.png

Comment: There is no point in looking at things like alignment as long as there are errors in your code. After an error, latex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, not necessarily producing sensible output.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I tried each figure as an image without any error but still I have an alignment problem...

Comment: Great, then please show this error free code

Comment: try overleaf link overleaf.com/1387338782zkctnvntsmdc  again .. Error free... without \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks again ... when I increase the data the alignment break again .. any general fix works with any data.. pls have look at the same overleaf link overleaf.com/1387338782zkctnvntsmdc

Comment: you can try the `T` option for the alignment or wrap each figure in a minipage of defined height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems:

- your graphs have different widths because some have an x label, others don't. If you scale them ([which you shouldn't do with elements that contain text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425453/36296)) to all have the same width, their height will no longer match. You can avoid this by using a dummy label for the other graphs.
- Empty lines and other white spaces are important! With all the empty lines in your code, you force line breaks between your images and all the unprotected line endings act as white spaces.

---

```
%\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%\usepackage{sfmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}%
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        title={Manufacture 1},
        set layers,axis background,
        grid=major,
        height=6cm, width=8.5cm,
        bar width=0.14cm,
        set layers,
        axis background,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
       major grid  style={dashed,draw=gray!15}, 
        ymin=1000, ymax=13000,
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.1cm}
        axis x line*=bottom,
        max space between ticks=14pt,
         xticklabel style={rotate=90,yshift=-0.05cm,xshift=0,color=black},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=true,
        ylabel={\strut Number of Sale },
        symbolic x coords={
     BMW, VW, Honda
          },
       xtick=data,
       enlarge x limits={abs=0.01},
       enlarge x limits=0.05,
        enlarge y limits=0.05,
       nodes near coords={
       }
    ]
    \addplot [draw=none, fill=blue] coordinates {
      (BMW,  12766) 
       (VW,  12766) 
       (Honda,  12766) 
    
      };

   \addplot [draw=none,fill=red] coordinates {
     (BMW,  10901)
     (VW, 6682)    
    (Honda, 9468)
  
  
     
     };
    
  
   \addplot [draw=none, fill=green] coordinates {
     (BMW, 8679)
     (VW, 3659)    
     (Honda,  7844)
    
        
      };
    
  \legend{car 1, car 2, car 3}
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}}%
%     \caption{Subfigure A}
        \label{fig:subfig8}%
    \end{subfigure}%
      \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}%
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
           \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        title={(b) Manufacture 2 },
        set layers,axis background,
        grid=major,
        height=6cm, width=8.5cm,
        max space between ticks=40pt,
        ymin=0,
        bar width=0.14cm,
        set layers,
        axis background,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
       major grid  style={dashed,draw=gray!15}, 
        ymin=1000, ymax=6000,
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.1cm}
        axis x line*=bottom,
        y tick label style={scaled ticks=base 10:-4},
           xticklabel style={rotate=90,yshift=0.1cm,xshift=0,color=black},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        ylabel={\strut},
        enlarge x limits=true,
        symbolic x coords={BMW, VW, Honda 
          },
       xtick=data,
       enlarge x limits={abs=0.01},
       enlarge x limits=0.05,
        enlarge y limits=0.05,
       nodes near coords={
       }
    ]
    \addplot [draw=none, fill=blue] coordinates {
     (BMW, 5153)
 (VW, 4522)
 (Honda, 4522)
      };
  \legend{Electric Car 2060 }
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}}
           \caption{Subfigure B}
        \label{fig:subfig9}
    \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \hspace*{\fill}%
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering
  \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        title={Manufacture 3},
        set layers,axis background,
        grid=major,
        height=6cm, width=8.5cm,
        ymin=0,
        bar width=0.14cm,
        set layers,
        axis background,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
       major grid  style={dashed,draw=gray!15}, 
        ymin=1000, ymax=21111,
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.1cm}
        axis x line*=bottom,
           xticklabel style={rotate=90,yshift=-0.05cm,xshift=0,color=black},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=true,
        ylabel={},
        symbolic x coords={
        BMW, VW, Honda
          },
       xtick=data,
               ylabel={\strut},
       enlarge x limits={abs=0.01},
       enlarge x limits=0.05,
        enlarge y limits=0.05,
       nodes near coords={
       }
    ]
    \addplot [draw=none, fill=red] coordinates {
(BMW, 19289)
 (VW, 20289)
 (Honda, 20289)
      };
   \addplot [draw=none,fill=blue] coordinates {
    (BMW,14653) 
 (VW, 20489)
      (VW, 20289)
       (Honda, 20289)
     };
   \addplot [draw=none, fill=green] coordinates {
   (BMW,14653) 
 (VW, 20489)};
 \legend{Car 1, Car 2, Car 3}
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}}
        \caption{Subfigure C}%
        \label{fig:subfig8}%%
    \end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your patient and clear explanation, the code work like a charm (as you fixed it -->overleaf).