# How to make tabular spread over multiple pages?

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, longtabu

I have a long table with 60 rows. I don't know how to spread it over multiple pages?

```
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering 
\caption{AAA}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|lrrr|rrr|}
\toprule
.... with 60 rows and 15 columns 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
 }
\label{BBB} 
\end{table}
```

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for the `longtable` package [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable)

Comment: Please don't use `\resizebox` for things which contain text https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425453/36296