# Error generated by graphicx with a table

Tags: tables, graphics, compilation-error

I am getting a compilation error when I use the package `graphicx` with a table that I generated from this website: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/. When I drop the `\usepackage{graphicx}` from the text and leave the table, the compilation works fine. On the other hand, when I take off the table and leave the `\usepackage{graphicx}`, the compilation also works fine. I need that both of them work together. Here is an example of the text that I am working with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sumário}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=[rgb]{0,0,0.6},citecolor=[rgb]{0,0,0.6},urlcolor=[rgb]{0,0,0.6}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\title{Regulation}
\author{Mateus Maciel}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{}{%
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\textbf{Variable}                            & \textbf{Granularity}              & \textbf{Period} & \textbf{Source} \\ \hline
Mobile broadband connections (3G and 4G)     & Municipality                      & 2007-2021       & Teleco          \\
Regulation Index                             & 100 most populated municipalities & 2016-2022       & Teleco          \\
Investment (number of antennas per provider) & Municipality                      & 1998-2022       & ANATEL          \\
Quality (internet speed)                     & Municipality                      & 2014-2022       & Ookla           \\
Population                                   & Municipality                      & 1991-2021       & IBGE            \\
GDP                                          & Municipality                      & 1999-2019       & IBGE            \\
Employment                                   & Municipality                      & 1985-2020       & IBGE            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Summary of the dataset}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, the error is caused by the second argument of `\resizebox` being empty. It should have been `{!}` or just `!`. But I agree with @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz that it is better not to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `\resizebox` for elements which contain text. [This usually gives a very poor result.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text)

Instead you could use a table like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sumário}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=[rgb]{0,0,0.6},citecolor=[rgb]{0,0,0.6},urlcolor=[rgb]{0,0,0.6}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\title{Regulation}
\author{Mateus Maciel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X>{\raggedright}p{3.5cm}ll@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Variable}                            & \textbf{Granularity}              & \textbf{Period} & \textbf{Source} \\ \midrule
Mobile broadband connections (3G and 4G)     & Municipality                      & 2007-2021       & Teleco          \\
Regulation Index                             & 100 most populated municipalities & 2016-2022       & Teleco          \\
Investment (number of antennas per provider) & Municipality                      & 1998-2022       & ANATEL          \\
Quality (internet speed)                     & Municipality                      & 2014-2022       & Ookla           \\
Population                                   & Municipality                      & 1991-2021       & IBGE            \\
GDP                                          & Municipality                      & 1999-2019       & IBGE            \\
Employment                                   & Municipality                      & 1985-2020       & IBGE            \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
\caption{Summary of the dataset}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thanks.

Comment: @MateusMaciel You're welcome!