# How to make pins with a square and X inside?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, circuitikz

I have spent one hour on this, one of my first Tikz circuit.
I'm trying to reprocedure this.

[image]

I haven't finished it though. I have some questions as I feel confused while making the drawing not sure if I do it right.

1. How would you create the pin with square and X inside like that?
2. My drawing is much bigger than the original. Is that normal?  I have to do this as the components's size seem to be 1cm long for each.
3. How can I add the "Supply Voltage" like that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border={5mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 0.5, voltage shift=0.5]
\draw [gray] (0,0) rectangle (4,9);
\draw (0,2) to [short,-*] ++(-1,0) coordinate(C1) to [short, -o]  ++(-3,0);
\draw (C1) to [C] ++(0,-1) node[ground]{};
\draw (0,4) to [short,-*] ++(-1,0) coordinate(C2) to [short] ++(-1,0)  to [cute inductor] ++(-1,0) to [short, -o]++(-1,0);
\draw (C2) to [C] ++(0,-1) node[ground]{};
\draw (0,6) to [short,-*] ++(-1,0) coordinate(C3) to [short] ++(-1,0)  to [cute inductor] ++(-1,0) to [short, -o]++(-1,0);
\draw (C3) to [C] ++(0,-1) node[ground]{};
\draw (0,8) to [short,-*] ++(-1,0) coordinate(C4) to [short] ++(-1,0)  to [cute inductor] ++(-1,0) to [short, -o]++(-1,0);
\draw (C4) to [C] ++(0,-1) node[ground]{};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american, siunitx]{circuitikz}  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape, scale=1,]
\ctikzset{
inductors/scale=0.5,
capacitors/scale=0.3,
power supplies/scale=0.5,
}
\draw[ultra thick, gray] (2.8,4) rectangle +(3,-5);

\draw[yshift=3cm] (0,0) to[short, o-] ++(1.6,0) to[cute inductor] ++(0.4,0) to[short,-*] ++(0.4,0) coordinate(C1) to[short] (2.8,0) node[osquarepole]{} to[short] ++(0.8,0) node[draw, fill=white, minimum height=1.2cm, minimum width=1.8cm, right]{Core};
\draw (C1) to[C] ++(0,-0.4) node[vee]{};

\draw[yshift=2cm] (0,0) to[short, o-] ++(1.2,0) to[cute inductor] ++(0.4,0) to[short,-*] ++(0.4,0) coordinate(C2) to[short] (2.8,0) node[osquarepole]{} to[short] ++(0.6,0) node[draw, fill=white, minimum height=1.2cm, minimum width=1.8cm, right]{Memory};
\draw (C2) to[C] ++(0,-0.4) node[vee]{};

\draw[yshift=1cm] (0,0) to[short, o-] ++(0.8,0) to[cute inductor] ++(0.4,0) to[short,-*] ++(0.4,0) coordinate(C3) to[short] (2.8,0) node[osquarepole]{} to[short] ++(0.4,0) node[draw, fill=white, minimum height=1.2cm, minimum width=1.8cm, right]{Camera};
\draw (C3) to[C] ++(0,-0.4) node[vee]{};

\draw[yshift=0cm] (0,0) to[short, o-] ++(0.8,0) to[short,-*] ++(0.4,0) coordinate(C4) to[short] (2.8,0) node[osquarepole]{} to[short] ++(0.2,0) node[draw, fill=white, minimum height=1.2cm, minimum width=1.8cm, right, align=center]{LED\\Driver};
\draw (C4) to[C] ++(0,-0.4) node[vee]{};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Circuit diagram with boxes]

**Edit:** With custom cross pins

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american, siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
cross/.style={
draw, fill=white, inner sep=2pt, 
path picture={\draw
(path picture bounding box.south east) --
(path picture bounding box.north west)
(path picture bounding box.south west) --
(path picture bounding box.north east);
}}}
\ctikzset{
inductors/scale=0.5,
capacitors/scale=0.3,
power supplies/scale=0.5,
}

\draw[ultra thick, gray] (2.8,4) rectangle +(3,-5);

\draw[yshift=3cm] (0,0) to[short, o-] ++(1.6,0) to[cute inductor] ++(0.4,0) to[short,-*] ++(0.4,0) coordinate(C1) to[short] (2.8,0) node[cross]{} to[short] ++(0.8,0) node[draw, fill=white, minimum height=1.2cm, minimum width=1.8cm, right]{Core};
\draw (C1) to[C] ++(0,-0.4) node[vee]{};

\draw[yshift=2cm] (0,0) to[short, o-] ++(1.2,0) to[cute inductor] ++(0.4,0) to[short,-*] ++(0.4,0) coordinate(C2) to[short] (2.8,0) node[cross]{} to[short] ++(0.6,0) node[draw, fill=white, minimum height=1.2cm, minimum width=1.8cm, right]{Memory};
\draw (C2) to[C] ++(0,-0.4) node[vee]{};

\draw[yshift=1cm] (0,0) to[short, o-] ++(0.8,0) to[cute inductor] ++(0.4,0) to[short,-*] ++(0.4,0) coordinate(C3) to[short] (2.8,0) node[cross]{} to[short] ++(0.4,0) node[draw, fill=white, minimum height=1.2cm, minimum width=1.8cm, right]{Camera};
\draw (C3) to[C] ++(0,-0.4) node[vee]{};

\draw[yshift=0cm] (0,0) to[short, o-] ++(0.8,0) to[short,-*] ++(0.4,0) coordinate(C4) to[short] (2.8,0) node[cross]{} to[short] ++(0.2,0) node[draw, fill=white, minimum height=1.2cm, minimum width=1.8cm, right, align=center]{LED\\Driver};
\draw (C4) to[C] ++(0,-0.4) node[vee]{};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Circuit diagram with boxes and custom pins]

Comment: Thank you, very nice figures. When you want to embed this into a .tex file, do you normally to make it exactly same as the place where you want to put or would you just draw it in whatever size you like and then scale it in the target location?

Comment: It depends on who you ask. Personally I would not scale text because a scaled text is not the same as change in font size. I would also not scale line widths. To stay consistent, I would where possible only use predefined sizes and widths `\normalsize`, `\small`, ... and `thin`, `thick`, ...

Comment: I'm a bit confused as llike the example above,  as people  would probably generate images of different sizes. And then if you want to export that and insert into a document, you could use scale. I wonder if there is any problem doing that way. The rectangle you drew is 3x5 size. I could probably did it with 6x10 or 9x15.  And all other components assume to small the same amount, then would there is any problem doing that way?

Comment: If you are happy scaling, then you should do it. I would not do it because of ugly font and inconsistent sizes throughout the document. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text

Comment: Then I can't just draw all my figures before writing a document as I'll have to know the size for each figure first.

Comment: How can I make the connectors bigger? 
` node[osquarepole, nodes width = 10pt]{}` isn't correct and I don't see example in the manual.

Comment: It is a TikZ node, you need to look i the TikZ manual. e.g. `node[osquarepole, scale=2]{}`

Comment: @hpekristiansen the fact that `power supplies/scale=-0.5` works at all is a (fortunate) coincidence. Better use `power supplies/scale=0.5` and use a `vee` node...

Comment: It is not important but the symbol in the original post is ground and it is actually confusing.