# latex table error "illegal unit of measure(pt inserted)" when trying to build a 9-column table

Tags: tables

I'm new to LaTex and I'm trying to write a table in Latex with 9 columns, it's a big one. I want the first column to be larger than the others, but the others can be small. I'm trying to work on a minimum working example first. but I keep getting error "illegal unit of measure(pt inserted)" and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code. please help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \caption{Classificação de Validações de Escalas de Fluxo: Revalidação, EFA, CFA e Índices de Bons Ajustes (GFI).}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{
            >{\small\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}
            *{8}{>{\small\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}}
        }
        \hline\hline
        Escala & Revalidada? (n1) & Teve EFA? (n2) & Teve CFA? (n3) & CFI = .95 (n4) & NFI = .95 (n5) & TLI = .95 (n6) & RMSEA = 0.05 (n7) & SRMR = 0.08 (n8)\\
        Work-Related Flow Inventory (WOLF) (bakker2008work) & 1 & 1 & 1 & .5 & .5 & .5 & 1 & 0\\
        [66] & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
        \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: use `\\ \relax`  so the following `[66]` is not seen as an argument

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but there are some unnecessary packages in your preamble. For example, you use a normal `tabular`, so you don't need to load `tabularray`. Also you might wnat to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text

Comment: just solved as the suggestion of David Carlisle said, my [66] was he fault f it. Thank you so much, David Carlisle!

Comment: Also, don't use resizebox on a table (which is the main thrust of samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's first link).