# Using etoolbox package to resize box automatically

Tags: etoolbox

I have hundreds of latex tables I generated using Stargazer. Almost all of these tables can be rectified by wrapping tabular as such \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular}}. I have already attempted to make adjustments using the stargazer function.

However, going back to latex, I thought that I would be able to simply use the etoolbox package and apply \BeforeBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{}
\AfterEndEnvironment{tabular}{}}. My hopes would be that every time \begin and \end tabular shows up in my code, it is autcomatically wrapped accordingly. However, it did not work. I suspect it is because latex interprets the {, and } quite literally. Any suggestions? I do not want to have to modify each individual table manually as I find myself having to regenerate tables quite often.

Comment: Using `\resizebox` will also scale tables up to fit `\textwidth`. Is that what you want, or only to scale down to fit `\textwidth`?

Comment: I typically want to scale down. I like all my tables fitting on the page, where as I don't mind if they are too small sometimes.

Comment: @r-learning-machine If you really want to scale your tables, have a look at the `adjustbox` package, but please note that the result will most likely look like a ransom letter with all the different font sizes. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text for some more reasons why scaling tables might not be the best of ideas.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz using adjustbox along with my original approach with etoolbox seems to have worked. Thanks.

Comment: @r-learning-machine You're welcome! ... and please don't show the result to anybody.

Answer (score 4):

You *might* do it, but don't blame me if something goes wrong, because some macro uses `tabular` internally… You've been warned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for context

\newsavebox{\scaletabular}

\AddToHook{env/tabular/before}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\scaletabular}%
}
\AddToHook{env/tabular/after}{%
  \end{lrbox}\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\usebox{\scaletabular}}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
111111 & 222222 & 333333 & 444444 & 555555 & 666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 & 999999 & 000000\\
111111 & 222222 & 333333 & 444444 & 555555 & 666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 & 999999 & 000000\\
111111 & 222222 & 333333 & 444444 & 555555 & 666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 & 999999 & 000000\\
111111 & 222222 & 333333 & 444444 & 555555 & 666666 & 77777777 & 88888888 & 999999 & 000000\\
\end{tabular}

\caption{Horrible table}

\end{table}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{cc}
AA & BB \\
CC & DD \\
\end{tabular}

\caption{Preposterously horrible table}

\end{table}

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You see what could go wrong, don't you? Tables should *never* be scaled up or down. This is even more obvious when not all of them exceed the text width. Well, one could add a test to see whether the table is “narrow”, but I wouldn't follow this path anyway, so I'll stop here.