Table Alignment Issue Specific To My Needs
I have a question please? and thank you in advance for acknowledging my issue.
The issue:
I have a table that I am trying to push down one column Confusion Matrix Des like here

this issues I am having is that this column Confusion Matrix Des won't push down to accommodate the text properly like here:

what I tried?:

I read the table documentations here https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables#Tables_with_a_fixed_width
But I am not seeing where I am going wrong in terms of the code.

I tried implement breaks lines between the text like so \\
that did not work.

I tried manipulating the wrapping of the text and columns using this


%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
%\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{% 

that did not work. I am not clear on the scripts nor do I know the terms of what this error is called or refers to.
My table code EXAMPLE:
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For better-looking tables
\usepackage{adjustbox} % For resizing tables

\begin{document}

vspace*{5mm}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
%\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Rating}      & \textbf{TP} & \textbf{TN} & \textbf{FP} & \textbf{FN} & \textbf{Confusion Matrix Description} \\ \hline
\textbf{Sitting} &
  3 &
  23 &
  1 &
  5 &
  \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}TP Preds ARE True\\ TN Preds NOT True\\ FP Preds NOT True But, Pred True\\ (It is ok)\\ FN Preds True But, Pred False\\ (Not OK)\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{1-5}
\textbf{Running}    & 4           & 21          & 3           & 4           &                                       \\ \cline{1-5}
\textbf{Skying}    & 6           & 17          & 3           & 2           &                                       \\ \cline{1-5}
\textbf{Eating} & 7           & 19          & 5           & 1           &                                       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{document}

** Can Someone Guide Me Please? would greatly appreciate this as I am lacking the understanding of something here and I am not certain of what this might be** Thank you in advance!!

You should never scale elements which contain text, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I voted to close this issue as requiring more details.  After having dozens of comments on your last question to clarify it as you failed to provide a usable example, you do exactly the same again. If you provide an example the question could be re-opened.

Code fences (```) must be on a line of their own. Do not put them in the same line as your code.

hey @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I am bit new to the latex. Mind explains a bit? I am not sure what your're referring to. am I at the basic basic basic level, if that helps. I am figuring things out via hands on and what I am stuck with I read and them come here for help when I don't know the terms. At every stage some things I get and some things are a bit complicated to understand, hence I am here.

ok got ya @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, apologies!

I highlighted the example and I placed pictures @DavidCarlisle. Aren't you seeing them there? I am lost here. what do you mean by I am not providing an example?!!?!?!

latex will not overprint text by default. You again show output from some unspecified document that has overprinting and then a fragment of code we can't run but if we did complete it to run it would not overprint any text so is not an example of your issue.

You showed some pictures of some document that has some text overprinting but you have not provided any  example code to produce that. As explained over and over again on your last question. Only post images of the document that  you post here, and post a document here that is related to your question.  Your question is about over-printing text so provide an example that produces some text that over-prints.

Hey @DavidCarlisle, maybe I am not clear!! I Don't understand what you mean by overprinting and fragmenting code. if I put the entire code here it would be a disaster. Hence I placed the piece of code that I am having issues with. if you mean by placing the \documentclass{report} \begin{document} and then ending those classes then the reason for this is that the script is extremely long and is being called by the main.tex page. Do you mean this??!!

Your image shows Not OK printed on top of  "Appendix: Model processing"  That is what you are asking about (I assume) You posted some code that can not be used with latex (it would give a missing begin document error) and if \documentclass was added so it could be run, it would not typeset Not OK or Appendix Model processing and would not make any text come on top of any other text so it is unrelated to your question.

As I explained last time your original document does not matter, make a small one page document that shows the problem, I linked to a "how to make a minimal example" post on the meta site, please follow that.

okay again @DavidCarlisle, Maybe you are not Understanding what I am saying. The code is too long hence I posted the script that's causing the problem. I get it. however I just updated the code. Maybe that can help.

@DavidCarlisle, MOST of what you are saying I AM literally googling trying my best to understand. I just updated the code to accommodate the change you are stating. Hopefully that is enough to then get some assistance to move forward?.

Better, thanks:-) Athough still you do not show any overprinted text you could have added a caption) and then replaced your current image by an image generated by the document posted here.

Someone provided a solution @DavidCarlisle,  I am not sure if it was you and if it is, thanx but that did not work? the text FN Preds True But, Pred False
(Not OK) is still outside the table as shown in my initial image.

I'd use two separate tables, as the items in your sixth column aren't related to the ones next to them.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For better-looking tables

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}lcccc@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Rating} & \textbf{TP} & \textbf{TN} & \textbf{FP} & \textbf{FN} \\
\midrule
Sitting & 3 & 23 & 1 & 5 \\
Running & 4 & 21 & 3 & 4 \\
Skying  & 6 & 17 & 3 & 2 \\
Eating  & 7 & 19 & 5 & 1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\hfill
{\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{\normalsize\bfseries\strut Confusion Matrix Description} \\
\midrule
  TP Preds ARE True \\
  TN Preds NOT True \\
  FP Preds NOT True But, Pred True (It~is~OK) \\
  FN Preds True But, Pred False (Not~OK) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\caption{Model Processing}

\end{table}

\end{document}


A possible improvement:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For better-looking tables
\usepackage{varwidth,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}lcccc@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Rating} & \textbf{TP} & \textbf{TN} & \textbf{FP} & \textbf{FN} \\
\midrule
Sitting & 3 & 23 & 1 & 5 \\
Running & 4 & 21 & 3 & 4 \\
Skying  & 6 & 17 & 3 & 2 \\
Eating  & 7 & 19 & 5 & 1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{\bfseries\strut Confusion Matrix Description} \\
\midrule
\begin{varwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
\footnotesize\raggedright
\begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=*,itemsep=2pt]
  \item TP Preds ARE True \\
  \item TN Preds NOT True \\
  \item FP Preds NOT True But, Pred True (It~is~OK) \\
  \item FN Preds True But, Pred False (Not~OK) \\
\end{itemize}
\end{varwidth} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Model Processing}

\end{table}

\end{document}



aww this is so much better @egreg. This is a professional look. thanx loads. One question though, is this \centering adjust the table to the centre of the page or the content will be centred in terms of font alignment?

@Simbadian Oh, well, actually \centering is irrelevant in either case.

I realised @egreg. thanx loads bruv. this worked

If you want a professional looking table, please read https://texdoc.org/serve/booktabs.pdf/0 and get rid of all the vertical lines.
To avoid confusion, I would not put your matrix description in the last column. This makes the entries look as if they correspond to the rows in the table. Use a caption instead.

That being said, I would suggest the tabularray package. This makes it very easy to merge cells:
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={clllll},
  vspan=even,
  hlines,
  vlines,
  row{1}={font=\bfseries},
  column{1}={font=\bfseries}
}
Rating & TP & TN & FP & FN & Confusion Matrix Description \\ 
Sitting & 3 & 23 & 1 & 5 & \SetCell[r=4]{} {TP Preds ARE True\\ TN Preds NOT True\\ FP Preds NOT True But, Pred True\\ (It is ok)\\ FN Preds True But, Pred False\\ (Not OK)} \\ 
Running & 4 & 21 & 3 & 4 & \\ 
Skying & 6 & 17 & 3 & 2 & \\ 
Eating & 7 & 19 & 5 & 1 & \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}



Hey @samcarter_is_at_topans the did not work. the issues persists

@Simbadian This works just fine and does not show your issue.

hey @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz it did WORK thanx so much pal. I shut down the computer and came back in and there is was THANX LOADS Really Appreciate this been  struggling with this for some hours well. Eternal grateful

@Simbadian Unless you actually show a small test document which allows me to reproduce the issue you have, all I can say is "This works fine".

I understand @
samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
however what I demonstrated as the issue is the test document. I didn't change anything. All I did was copy what you suggested and then shut down my pc and came back in again and there it was. Not sure what was causing the error But it worked and WHORAY!! thanx loads for assisting, I am learning.
